# GriddB Java implementation throws an Receive Timed Out error

Tags: java, griddb

I have some Java code that I am running to learn and use griddb. My Griddb is running in a docker container. When I execute the program, I get a runtime error that there is a SocketTimeoutException while at the same time, the program keeps going in an infinite loop, throwing the same error at intervals. Could this error be from how the code is structured or the griddb server itself and how do I fix this? The screenshot below shows the error I am getting. [image]
And here is the code:

```
package org.griddb;

import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.*;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

public class GridDBTest {

static class Person {
    @RowKey
    public String name;
    private int age;
}

static class HeartRate {
    @RowKey
    Date ts;
    int heartRate;
    String activity;
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws GSException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("notificationAddress", "239.0.0.1");
    props.setProperty("notificationPort", "31999");
    props.setProperty("clusterName", "defaultCluster");
    props.setProperty("user", "admin");
    props.setProperty("password", "admin");
    GridStore store = GridStoreFactory.getInstance().getGridStore(props);

    Collection<String, Person> people = store.putCollection("PEOPLE", Person.class);

    Query<Person> query = people.query("select * where name = 'John'");
    RowSet<Person> rs = query.fetch(false);
    Person person1 = new Person();
    person1.age=50;
    person1.name="John";
    TimeSeries<Person> personTimeSeries = store.putTimeSeries("Admin_"+person1.name, 
    Person.class);
    personTimeSeries.put(person1);
    while (rs.hasNext()) {
        // Update the searched Row
        Person person2 = rs.next();
        System.out.println("Name: "+ person2.name +" Age: "+ person2.age);
    }
    store.close();
}
```